# Can I just use the libraries from FFmpeg in an Android app?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, cygwin, rtsp

After some time on the Web, I found that I have to use the FFmpeg in my app. I found a lot of things related with Android and FFmpeg. I just want to use FFmpeg, but I can't create the libraries and also I don't know how I can use them.

I just want to receive an RTSP stream and then somehow put it in a videoview or mediaplayer. I have the NDK already installed in my eclipse, and I know how to use CYGWIN.

Comment: I need help to create the libraries, and how I can I use them in may app

Comment: Check out https://github.com/madhavanmalolan/ffmpegandroidlibrary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to use the FFmpeg library in my Android app following this tutorial: [Tutorial Link](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/)
which is really good. I created the library, called right in app too.
But what I wanted was streaming links with MMS protocol and I couldn't do it, because I don't know how to work with native methods, so I'm using the [vitamio plugin](http://vitamio.org/).
It's very simple. If you discover how to use the FFmpeg library appropriately please share with us.

Sorry for bad English, not my native language.

Comment: oh yeah, another thing... I think that the native mediaplayer from android supports rtsp streaming

Comment: I found a open source that already have the libraries and seems that you just have to call the functions that you need, I not test yet but seems to me that is a good thing for me that just need the libraries...http://code.google.com/p/android-fplayer/source/browse/trunk/src/cz/havlena/ffmpeg/ui?spec=svn2&r=2

Comment: hey, the vimatio link is not getting opened. Please update the right link.

Comment: Do we need to pay for using Vitamo plugin? It seems it is not free.

Answer (score 0):

Android supports the RTSP Streaming Protocol by default, using the MediaPlayer Only i was able to stream RTSP. But the limitation is that you cannot manipulate or customize the Media, for that you have to use Libraries like FFMPEG,Vlcj 
You can Set up FFMPEG environment by following this link http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/

I haven't tried the vlcj on android, but works on Desktop applications very well.
Hope this is helpful